# stitched border effect in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, photoshop

Currently my border looks like this:

[image: My border]

The CSS used is:

```
.widget > h5 {
    border: 3px double #cccccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

My question is how do i create a stitched effect similar to this:

[image: this is what i want]

```
.stitched_element {
border: 2px dashed  #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #ff0030;
}
```

Comment: With the triangle at the bottom or without it?

Comment: with and without if possible :)

Comment: 2 divs, both with `border: dashed` and a bit of padding between them: https://jsfiddle.net/e9ytdyya/

Comment: try this `.dashed {border-style: dashed;}`

Comment: Just a try with padding: https://jsfiddle.net/EdmondWang/659Lxo90/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you don't need the triangle**, use [Edmond Wang's solution](https://jsfiddle.net/EdmondWang/659Lxo90/) (which is working everywhere).

---

But **if you do need it**, you'll have to create it using [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) or [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/SVG_and_CSS), which is more complex and [may not work on every browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas).

I still made a [fiddle where you can see the result](https://jsfiddle.net/09fq526u/1/) using canvas :

```html
<canvas width="500"></canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Then use ctx to draw what you need e.g :
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100); 
// Draws a black rectangle at (X,Y)=(0,0) and width & height = 100px
```